# How can I locate a parent of an element know by child value using CodeceptJS

Tags: testing, codeceptjs

basically I have the following:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">title 1</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">title 2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">title 3</div>
</div>
```

I want to locate the container that has "title 2" as title, without Xpath Please. I mean just css selectors and codeceptJS functions. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```js
locate(".container").withChild(".title").withText("title 2")
```

See the [locator builder documentation](https://codecept.io/locators/#locator-builder) for more info.